# Java - resolve ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, objectinputstream

Please tell me how to differentiate objects from ObjectInputStream.Like whether it is String , Image or etc...?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to know what to expect and cast it. You may also do checks with instanceof or do something more sophisticated like register handlers in a map where you do

```
map.get(object.getClass()).handle(object);
```

But most importantly, you **must** know what objects you can expect to write proper handling code.

Comment: i am able to read the single objects from it in below manner:`Class1 obj1= (Class1) oi.readObject();
                     Class2 obj2= (Class2) oi.readObject();` .But how can i fetch and differentiate btw objects of same type say i have stored 2 object of Class1 so how can we read that and assign into a third var say Class1 obj3: